# JSON - passing form input value as json string went wrong

Tags: javascript, json, joomla3.0, custom-fields, html-escape-characters

I'm using an `<input type="text">` to store a collection of form values that are processed via JavaScript.

In JavaScript the value has this structure

```js
{"family":"Johnsons","Johnsons":{"girls":["Anna","Bella"],"boys":["Robert"]}}
```

so the above input looks like this BEFORE form submit

```
<input id="main" type="text" 
       value="{"family":"Johnsons","Johnsons":{"girls":["Anna","Bella"],"boys":["Robert"]}}">
```

After form save, I get this instead

```
<input id="main" type="text" 
       value="{"family":"Johnsons","girls":"Anna","boys":"Robert"}">
```

The input's value is set via this code, and I suspect this has to be the problem:

```js
// the input
var main = document.getElementById('main');
// the content structure before JSON.stringify
var content = {
  family: "Johnsons",
  Johnsons: {
    girls: [ "Ana", "Bela" ],
    boys: [ "Robert" ]
  }
};
main.value = JSON.stringify(content).replace( /\"/g, '\"');
main.setAttribute('value', main.value);

console.log(main.value);
```

```html
<input id="main" type="text">
```

I need a vanilla JavaScript solution, but I thank you for any reply.

Comment: Could you provide a working example of your code? That means including the necessary HTML and JavaScript so we can help you more accurately.

Comment: Done. Have a look and let me know what's on your mind.

Comment: Are these quotes really the way your html looks: `value="{"family":"Johnsons","Johnsons":{"girls":["Anna","Bella"],"boys":["Robert"]}}"` that doesn't seem right.
`

Comment: Yes @MarkMeyer that's the way it looks, please check the updated post.

Comment: you shouldn't need to escape the quotes when using `setAttribute`

Comment: The way the HTML looks BEFORE submit is not valid HTML. The `"` in value must be escaped.

Comment: just to narrow down things down, what happens when you echo your value to the screen on submit instead of showing in post processing after adding it back to the input?

Comment: Good question @imvain2 in my php the value coming from database after form submit is `array(3) { ["family"]=> string(8) "Johnsons" ["girls"]=> string(4) "Anna" ["boys"]=> string(6) "Robert" }`

Comment: @thednp, what about AFTER submit but BEFORE adding it to the database? Maybe a simple `echo $_POST["field_name"];exit;` I'm assuming this is getting added via ajAX as your input doesn't have a name?

Comment: The reason I'm pushing for the output to be echoed is I have a strong feeling this is server side not client side. After all the client side testing and suggestions, they all submit the value correctly. Which suggests it must be a problem server side.

Comment: I don't exactly know where to use `$_POST` in Joomla, but I will look into this as well.

Comment: Using `$_POST` In Joomla is a no-no.  There are helper functions available for accessing POST and GET data.  I would like to see your generated source code, how your script is submitting, and where the relevant files are positioned in your Joomla site.  If you _need_ to pass the json via without ajax, I recommend a hidden field so that users don't corrupt the string.  If this is ajax, I wouldn't bother writing it into the form - I'd inject it directly into the post process.  We need more info to help you.

Answer (score 2):

Just stringify no need to `.replace()`. Also note that the input is assigned a `name` attribute with the value of `"content"` so when the form is submitted the input's value will be sent to the server.

```js
var form = document.forms.form;
var main = form.elements.main;

var content = {
  family: "Johnsons",
  Johnsons: {
    girls: ["Ana", "Bela"],
    boys: ["Robert"]
  }
};

main.value = JSON.stringify(content);

console.log(main.value);
```

```html
<form id='form' action='https://www.hashemian.com/tools/form-post-tester.php' method='post' target='response'>
  <input id="main" name='content' type="text"><input type='submit'>
</form>
<iframe name='response'></iframe>
```

Comment: This won't do, I came here because I tried everything.

Comment: Explain what won't do and I doubt you've done everything or you did do everything and then didn't recognize a solution. I've updated the answer as a form that submits to a live test server. The response is displayed in the iframe below.

Comment: Thanks for the input man, now I have to figure out how to decode that thing. Will let you know when I'm done testing asap.

Comment: I just tried all the above, including setting `autocomplete="off"` and `spellcheck="false"`, I seem to have to investigate what Joomla does on form submit because on your form tester demo looks to work like a breeze.

Comment: You might want to add the joomla tag or make a new question that references this question with the joomla tag of course.

Comment: ...or even use your [joomla.se] Stack Exchange account to ask the community over there.  But honestly, if you are just holding the data to pass it with the form submission, just store it as a javascript `const` then submit that constant with the other form data.  No need to add it to the markup if the user isn't meant to play with it.

Answer (score 1):

You can try
**edited**

```js
var main = document.getElementById('main');

var content = {
  family: "Johnsons",
  Johnsons: {
    girls: [ "Ana", "Bela" ],
    boys: [ "Robert" ]
  }
};
main.value = JSON.stringify(content, undefined, 2);
```

```html
<input id="main"></input>
```

`pre` tells the browser engine that the content inside is pre-formatted and it can be displayed without any modification. So browser will not remove white spaces, new lines etc. code is for making it more semantic and denotes that the content inside is a code snippet. It has nothing to with formatting. It is advised to use like this, `<pre><code> /* Your code snippet here. */ </code></pre>`

```
<pre id="main"></pre>
```

Comment: Thanks for the input, it's an interesting approach, however, I need the `<input>` as part of a form. I also tried `JSON.stringify(content, undefined, 2)` after form submission, problem is still there.

Comment: Why is there a closing `</input>`?